Using variable trying to click on the element in karate
Trying to access variable from json file and using it in karate. But not working as expected.
* def elements = karate.read('../elements.json')
* print 'driverNoInput:', elements.driverNoInput
elements.json
{
"driverNoInput": "driverElement"
}
Code:

waitFor(elements.driverNoInput).click()
call sleep(10000)

Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "locator" is null.
Is this the correct way to use this? Need some solution..

this is a mishmash of inadequate info, so I think you have to troubleshoot this yourself. try following this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and also read this before asking questions on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

elements.json
{
  "login_button": "#login-button"
}

Feature file
Feature: POM

  Background: POM background
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
    * driver 'https://www.saucedemo.com/'
    * delay(3000)
    * def elements = karate.read('classpath:testdata/elements.json')

    Scenario: POM 1
    *  waitFor(elements.login_button).click()
    *  print 'login_button:', elements.login_button
    * delay(3000)

html report

I have created elements.json file under src/test/java in a folder called testdata. After that using read method called the file in background section and stored it into a variable called elements. This will work.
